# updating ubuntu while dual booting win8

Tags: grub2, dual-boot, windows-8, uefi

ive had great help from u guys and you guys are doing a gr8 job ..thanks for that
i had a small doubt ,
i have a laptop that comes with win8 pre installed ,so the UEFI crap is there ... :( 
i have duall booted it along with ubuntu 13.04 by turning secure boot off ..
my doubt is ,if say i want to upgrade to 13.10 (when it comes out) ,should i mess around with the secure boot option or the BIOS or can i normally just update it via update centre ? by doing this ,can i still keep win8 ? 
thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such an update *should* pose no more of a problem than on an earlier computer or earlier updates (say, 11.04 to 11.10 on a BIOS-based computer). Of course, *should* doesn't always pan out in the real world.

In theory, you should (there's that word again) have been able to install Ubuntu 13.04 with Secure Boot enabled; since version 12.10 (including 12.04.2, but not 12.04), Ubuntu has supported Secure Boot. In practice, this doesn't always work, although I've not studied Ubuntu's Secure Boot problems in enough detail to know why. Certainly there's no need to enable Secure Boot for an update, though; there are plenty of EFI/UEFI systems that lack Secure Boot entirely, so it would be insane of the Ubuntu developers to require that Secure Boot be active in future updates. If you're booting with Secure Boot turned off, an update should still work with Secure Boot disabled.